# Pass Value from one sub report to another sub report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to get the sum(qty) from sub_report a and use it in sub_report b because I will show them like this:

```
Banana    PHP 10.00x1    10 - sub report a
Tax       PHP 3.00x1      3 - sub report b      
          PHP 2.00x1      2
          PHP 5.00x1      5

Banana    PHP 10.00x1    10 - sub report a
Tax       PHP 3.00x1      3 - sub report b      
          PHP 2.00x1      2
          PHP 5.00x1      5
```

After I merge this the result below because it shows the same data

```
Banana    PHP 10.00x2    20 - sub report a
Tax       PHP 3.00x3      9 - sub report b      
          PHP 2.00x3      6
          PHP 5.00x3     15
```

I don't know why I'm getting sum of qty as 3 instead of 2 in sub report b so it results to wrong total.

Desired Result:

```
Banana    PHP 10.00x2    20 - sub report a
Tax       PHP 3.00x2      6 - sub report b      
          PHP 2.00x2      4
          PHP 5.00x2     10
```

The two sub report are placed in the main report in one group. 
Please help me with this thank you.

Comment: somewhere it is double counting...check where did you place the sub report and where are you retriving the values

Comment: if you place the shared variable you are using to get the value from your subreport on your main report, does it show the right amount?

Comment: no it shows 0 result so I just make a shared variable from the sub report to be shared to other sub reports